# SharePoint code generating SQL, how can I trace this back to my code?

Tags: sql, dashboard, developer

Looks like my SharePoint code is generating SQL, it runs 3 to 4 times per page request. It all adds up to approximately 4 seconds from what I can see on the developer dashboard.
I'm using spmonitored scope in my methods but non of the executions times correlate with the db execution time.

The query starts off as

SELECT t39.*, t40.[ntext8] ... etc

The tables being queries are:
'AllUserData'
'AllDocs'
'Worktable'
'AllUserDataJunctions'

how can I trace this back to my code?

Thanks,
Cody.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add some `Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPMonitoredScope` to your code. With them you can measure a part of your code. The Developer Dashboard shows the time used for this scopes.

Use this with a using statment around the code of want to measure:

```
using (new SPMonitoredScope("My Scope Name"))
{
   doSomeWork(); 
}
```

See [msdn: Using SPMonitoredScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff512758%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: Already have spmonitored scope in there